# CSS display div below table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have side by side tables in a div container and then another div element that I want to display under the tables. At anytime the tables may have more rows than each other. How do I get the "Logs" div to always display below the table with the most rows?

http://jsfiddle.net/Tc2wA/10/

```
<div id="table_container">
  <table border="1" class="table_tpr">
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">1</td>
      <td width="50%">12345678912345678912345679821345678941536321</td>
      <td width="20%">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">1</td>
      <td width="50%">12345678912345678912345679821345678941536321</td>
      <td width="20%">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10%">1</td>
      <td width="50%">12345678912345678912345679821345678941536321</td>
      <td width="20%">2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1" class="table_loa">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br />
<div class="maintitle">Logs</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to clear the floating elements.

See working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/Tc2wA/12/

I added the class `clearfix` that should clear your floating elements and won't have problems in any browser:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; }
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; }
```

Then you juse give the class to the `#table_container` element:

```
<div id="table_container" class="clearfix">
```

Comment: @JonErickson I was worried that you realize the proper clearing of floating elements haha. Here the `<br>` tag is not being ignored as the floating elements are cleared correctly. If this is your answer please mark it as solution with the green check.

Comment: Carlos, let me just give you 1000 rep. It's nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add some css for your maintitle class:

```
.maintitle{
    clear:both;
}
```

This will make sure the Logs are always displayed below your tables.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/Tc2wA/11/

Comment: It appears as if the OP wants the div to appear under the specific table with more rows, not just below both tables.

Comment: Awesome thanks. How can I add a break or padding so that the maintitle does not sit touching the bottom of the table?

Comment: @j08691 Negative, I would like it to display under both as if it was a new header to a new section of the website.

Comment: That's not how you've formulated your question. I'm writing a bit of jQuery for you at the moment, but that's useless then.

Comment: @JonErickson see my answer. Use the `clearfix` class, be careful with `clear: both`. You may have problems in different browsers clearing the floating elements.

Comment: @JonErickson - Well in that case this is pretty simple.

Comment: sure - just add padding: 
     .maintitle{
      clear:both;
      padding-top: 5px;
      }
you can also center the div if you'd like

Comment: @JonErickson be careful, this answer is not actually clearing the floating elements. If you notice, the `<br>` tag is being ignored because there is no space created between `#table_container` and `.maintitle`. See that `#table_container` still has `height` 0. Please use the `clearfix` class as I said in my answer.